# Critical point of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, extreme-value-theorem

For the function $f(x,y)=x^2y^2 + \frac{1}{y} + \ln(\frac{1}{x})$ I get two critical points, namely $P_1 =\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}},1 \right)$ and $P_2 =\left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}},1 \right)$. However the domain of my function is $Df=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; x > 0, y \neq 0\}$.

Now point $P_2$ is not in the domain of function$f$ and I think it should be immediately ruled out, but the Hessian matrix shows that this point is a minimum. Should it be ruled out or not?

Comment: Your mistake in saying that $P_2$ is a critical point. When you go about finding critical points, you're already only considering points in the domain of $f$, therefore $P_2$ wasn't valid to start with. It should be ruled out.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, $P_2$ is a solution of the system, but isn’t in the domain of $f$, so it can’t be a critical point of $f$.

Comment: The invalidity of $P_2$ arises from the fact that the (maximal) domain of $\ln(1/x)$ is $\mathbb{R}_+$, but the (maximal) domain of its derivative, namely $-1/x$, is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: This happens because $f(x,y)=x^2y^2 + \frac{1}{y} + ln(\frac{1}{x})$ is not a function. You missed to write the domain and codomain. A type-theoretic error if you like. Functions have domain, codomain and a way to assign elements from the domain to the codomain.

Comment: Not every solution of the "last equation" is a solution of the original problem. By the way: Please write $P_1=\bigl(\sqrt{1\over2},1\bigr)$, because $P_1$ is not a function to be evaluated at $\bigl(\sqrt{1\over2},1\bigr)$.

Comment: I meant that $P_2$ is a solution to the equation from $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$. The function was an exercise that I found in a book, so I only had to calculate the minima/maxima.